Simulating half-bridge driver IR2104
I have recently moved from Multisim to LTspice and ngSpice in KiCAD, but I'm having problems simulating anything using the IR2104 driver.
I have tried multiple simulation models, but none worked for me, either the simulation failed completely or the driver doesn't apear to function correctely :(
If someone more experienced in SPICE could help, I would be grateful :)
KiCAD project containg simulation and models:
https://we.tl/t-tpDzmcd0pp




It's difficult to suggest anything from the circuit that looks correct at first sight. I would reduce the bootstrap cap. from 1 µF to 100 nF and check with a differential probe that it is well charged above the upper-side driver UVLO. A .IC may also help. I know that some models need a transition on the $V_{cc}$ for proper internal initialization. You may want to PWL your $V_1$ source from a few volts to 14 V in 100 µs for instance.

Thanks for the tips. I tried specifying the initial conditions, but sadly that didn’t help. I also attempted to implement the ramp-up, but unfortunately, KiCad only offers options for running a transient simulation or using a variable power source for calculating gain. I tried that approach, but now there isn’t any signal input :D There is an option of setting the simulation using commands like .tran 100n 1m but im having trouble putting the ramp up there :(

.tran 1m startup ensures the power sources start from 0V and rise up to their DC value. Might be wort giving a try.

@RohatKılıç Unfortunatly the argument is not being accepted :( "Error on line 7 or its substitute:
.tran 100n 1m startup
Error: unknown parameter on .tran - ignored"

@OnHai because your SPICE command .tran 100n 1m startup translates into "run the simulation for 100 nanoseconds but start collecting data after 1 millisecond" which is meaningless because the simulator can't start collecting data after the simulation is completed. Try .tran 10m startup instead.

@RohatKılıç well that results in this: "Error on line 7 or its substitute:
.tran 10m startup
TSTOP is invalid, must be greater than zero."

@OnHai oh, apparently there's no startup keyword in ngspice (sigh).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@RohatKılıç it seems that way, and do you think if i redo the circuit in LTspice these commands would work?
